# Equation of a line reflected in a plane

Tags: vectors

> The line $l_1$ has the equation $r=(6i+2−2k)+λ(4i+5j−k)$ and the plane $π_1: 2x−y+4z=4$, the line $l_2$ is the reflection of $l_1$ in the plane π1. Find the exact vector equation of line $l_2$

So the line intersects the plane when $λ=−2$, giving the point $(−2,−8,0)$ which will be common on $l_1$ and $l_2$. I have managed to get a direction vector of $(92/21i + 206/21j +26/21k)$ but I don't think this is right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [a previous question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047370/265466) that has an answer. If you don’t like that answer or don’t understand it, you should post comments there instead of reposting the same question.